# Disabled attribute in select not working (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is one question when i apply `[disabled]="true"` or `[disabled]="false"` . It won't work as of now.

I don't know what is the issue
`<select formControlName="actionSelected" [disabled]="condition" >`

When i inspect it shows `ng-reflect-is-disabled="true"` in the select.

Comment: Would you share some codes..

Comment: @SarathMohandas i think its enough code.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it help. You have to read some document

```
<select [attr.disabled]="CONDITION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when i set `<select formControlName="actionSelected" [attr.disabled]="condition ? '' : null" >`

Thanks for the help!